# Compute integral of periodic function numerical spectrally

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, fourier-transform, numerical-calculus, quadrature

I have a $2\pi$-periodic function $f(x)$, and I want to calculate numerically the integral $\int_{0}^{\alpha}f(x)dx$ where $\alpha$ is a point in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I have the function evaluated in the points of a grid on that interval. I know that schemes like the trapezoidal rule converges spectrally for periodic functions, then I can calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)dx$ accuratelly with the points that I have. However, this rule do not allow me to calculate the integral up to $\alpha$, a point inside the interval, with the accuracy I need. I wonder if there is a scheme that allows me to perform this with spectral accuracy, for example using the fourier transform or something like that.

Comment: What is "spectral accuracy" supposed to mean? Ghostly accuracy, maybe? If it's a sufficiently smooth periodic function, why don't you just compute its Fourier series, and integrate that, term by term?

Comment: Yeah, I think they are the same, spectral mean something like exponential convergence in the number of points

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is the indicator function of the interval $[0,\alpha]$, you want to compute
$$\int_0^{2\pi} u(x) f(x) \; dx = 2 \pi \sum_{n=-\infty} \overline{\hat{u}_n} \hat{f}_n$$
where $\hat{u}_n$ and $\hat{f}_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $u$ and $f$.

Comment: Should there be a convolution in Fourier space corresponding to the pointwise product in $x$-space?

Comment: This is Parseval's theorem.

Comment: Ah I see where I was confused. Taking the conjugate of the coefficients of the indicator function is equivalent to the discrete convolution of the Fourier coefficients of $u$ and $f$

Comment: Taking the DFT of a indicator function would not introduce much error?